# Animating a python plotly Heatmap

Tags: python-3.x, heatmap, plotly-python

I want to animate a plotly heatmap using a numpy 2D array. My input array is initialized as a variable which is changing over time. I want to animate the 2D array. I have tried several stuff and my current version plots the heat map but in different tabs of the same browser.

I want the each frame to be animated in the same tab

Here is my code segment;

```
    for j in range(2, len(thermal_np)):  # ---->As the first 2 values are corrupted from the sensor
        row_array = np.array(thermal_np[j])
        # result_array1.append(row_array)
        y = np.array(thermal_np[j])
        final_therm = y.reshape(24, 32)  # ---->Reshaping the temperature array to 24x32 final thermal array

        fig.data = []  # ---->Clearing the previous data from the plot
        fig.add_trace(go.Heatmap(z=final_therm, colorscale='jet', showscale=True, zsmooth='best'))
        fig = go.Figure(data=go.Heatmap(z=final_therm, colorscale='jet', showscale=True, zsmooth='best'), layout=layout,
                        frames=[go.Frame(data=[go.Heatmap(z=final_therm[i])],
                                         layout=go.Layout(title_text=f"Frame {i}"))
                                for i in range(1, j)])
        fig.update_layout(
            margin=dict(t=200, r=200, b=200, l=200),
            showlegend=False,
            width=1000, height=1000,
            autosize=True)

        fig.show()
        time.sleep(1)  # add a delay of 1 second between each plot
```

I was expecting an animated heatmap in the same tab of the browser. But I got a heatmap where each frame is displayed in sperate tabs

Comment: Check out the doc : https://plotly.com/python/animations/, there are a few examples, no heatmap though, but the principles remain the same for all trace types.